# How to set material to gameobject dynamically using c# script in unity?

Tags: c#, unity, 3d-meshes

I want to set material to a gameobject in unity using c# script.

I am using this code to set the material of mesh renderer attached to the gameobject -

```
MeshRenderer mesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mesh.materials[0] = materialsCopy[0];
```

here materialsCopy is an array of type Materials which I've made public and I am attaching the Materials by drag & drop to the materialsCopy but when I run the game I get a white colored mesh instead of the set material of the 0 index materialsCopy. The 0 indexed materialsCopy has albedo set to an image. I want this image to get attached to the gameobject. How should I proceed ?

In addition to this I am also getting a warning - Tiled GPU perf. warning: RenderTexture color surface  (0x0) was not cleared/discarded, doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Renderer rend = GetComponent<Renderer> (); 
rend.material = materialsCopy[0];
```

Comment: To give a bit more context about why this works: `renderer.materials` returns a *copy* of the internal materials array. So assigning `renderer.materials[0] = foo` only sets the first material *of the copy*. Assigning a material to `renderer.material` or assigning an array of materials to `renderer.materials` *replaces* the current contents, instead of modifying a copy.